# rvest jump_to with special characters

Tags: r, rvest

I'm having difficulty getting rvest to jump_to url's with special characters in them. When I type the link into chrome it works, but in R / rvest I get an error:

> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle=handle) :
>   Could not resolve host: NA

URL's that have issues:

> http://incrediblewinestore.com/ProductDetail.asp?title=-You-Had-Me-At-Merlot--Napkins&UPCCode=876718049392
>
> http://incrediblewinestore.com/ProductDetail.asp?title=10-BARREL-RASPBERRY-CRUSH-6PK&UPCCode=`851538002611
>
> http://incrediblewinestore.com/ProductDetail.asp?title=14-HANDS-CABERNET-SAUVIGNON&UPCCode=\088586001895

URL that works:

> http://incrediblewinestore.com/ProductDetail.asp?title=Cuarenta-y-Tres-Liqueur-43&UPCCode=029929115411

The code I've tried:

```
library(stringr)
library(rvest)
# Load first page, try to go to search, but expect age-check
iws_ac_url <- "http://incrediblewinestore.com"
iws_session <- html_session(iws_ac_url)

age_gate <- iws_session %>% 
  html_node("form[name='AgeGate']")

age_gate <- html_form(age_gate)

age_gate <- set_values(age_gate, PageAction = 'Yes21')

# Submit form and enter the rest of the site
iws_site <- submit_form(iws_session,age_gate)

# Unworking Links
temp_link <- paste0("http://incrediblewinestore.com","/ProductDetail.asp?title=<i>-You-Had-Me-At-Merlot-<i>-Napkins&UPCCode=876718049392")
iws_site %>% jump_to(temp_link)

temp_link <- paste0("http://incrediblewinestore.com","/ProductDetail.asp?title=10-BARREL-RASPBERRY-CRUSH-6PK&UPCCode=`851538002611")
iws_site %>% jump_to(temp_link)

# Working link
temp_link <- paste0("http://incrediblewinestore.com","/ProductDetail.asp?title=Cuarenta-y-Tres-Liqueur-43&UPCCode=029929115411")
iws_site %>% jump_to(temp_link)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, once I found the answer I was shocked at the simplicity. Just needed the function name: `URLencode(url,reserved = FALSE)`

```
temp_link <- paste0("http://incrediblewinestore.com",URLencode("/ProductDetail.asp?title=10-BARREL-RASPBERRY-CRUSH-6PK&UPCCode=`851538002611",reserved = FALSE))
```

The secret was that I needed a function which would not encode reserved characters such as = ? & . The other function I tried was converting all the characters.